# Upgrading packages over a large amount of servers

Tags: centos, redhat, yum, package-management

I have a large amount of CentOS servers that I need to periodically upgrade packages on. How can I combine automated upgrades but still retain control?

Some of my issues with fully automated upgrades:

- Locally modified files, esp. for configuration could break a service
- Kernel/glibc upgrades require a reboot, but servers cannot randomly be rebooted

Answer (score 3):

"A large amount of servers that could not be random rebooted" - this sounds like a problem. Our friend [Chaos Monkey](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2011/04/working-with-the-chaos-monkey.html) would kill you. My suggestion is to follow best practices and be able to kill any server anytime. It will save you a lot of headache.

Having locally modified files could be also a lot of pain. As you have a lot of servers, then you should have a software for managing their configuration (Chef, puppet, ansible). After upgrade just run such software to make sure that your configuration is not overwritten.

Comment: +1. Definitely a setup asking for a desaster. Any larger server setup should be build with the concept of ingrained redundancy because servers WILL half reboot. Half as in: going down and not come up again ;)

Comment: Maybe I used the wrong phrasing. Servers do handle a reboot but will naturally have services that arent accessible during the reboot. Before a reboot can be performed, customers must be informed that "this-and-that will be inaccessible for a few minutes". Does that make sense?

Comment: And for my particular case, configuration management with puppet is there. But I dont think that configuration management is relevant for the question?

Comment: @c0dem4gnetic `ensure => latest;` Voila! Instant automatic updates.

Comment: `ensure => latest` will without a doubt lead to me having the latest package version. It will also without a doubt lead to issues if the update generates rpmsave/rpmnew files.